# BASH command_not_found_handle () -- does not suggest solution

Tags: bash, built-in

I am trying to get the `command_not_found_handle` working in my Scientific Linux. I installed the `command-not-found` package

```
`sudo yum install PackageKit-command-not-found.x86_64`
```

and now if I issue `type command_not_found_handle` I get:

```
[JmZ:/usr/lib]-->type command_not_found_handle
command_not_found_handle is a function
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    runcnf=1;
    retval=127;
    [ ! -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ] && runcnf=0;
    [ ! -x /usr/sbin/packagekitd ] && runcnf=0;
    if [ $runcnf -eq 1 ]; then
        /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found $1;
        retval=$?;
    else
        echo "bash: $1: command not found";
    fi;
    return $retval
}
```

which I did not see before installing the package.  If I now issue a command for some program (e.g., gcl) that is not installed, I just get the following:

```
[JmZ:/usr/lib]-->gcl
Command not found.
```

whereas if I do something similar in my Ubuntu, I get:

```
JmZ@ubuntu:~$ gcl
The program 'gcl' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcl
```

I would like to get similar functionality in Scientific Linux.  How do I set this up?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try fulfilling the conditions given?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by "fulfilling the conditions given."  I don't have much experience with shell scripting so I'm working on deciphering the script.

Comment: you probably need the packagekit installed and a running dbus daemon, configured to place its interface in /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket (through a symlink)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I'm running Linux Mint, version somewhere between 14 and 16, and my `command_not_found_handle` is this:

```
command_not_found_handle is a function
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1;
        return $?;
    else
        return 127;
    fi
}
```

That script references [this page](https://launchpad.net/command-not-found), which has a tarball download that ought to have everything you need.